# Syntax error, '(' - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, syntax, error-handling

I'm working with C# (in asp.net) and i'm trying to add nested `IF` in a correct way but i keep getting this 3 errors with the second `if (chk1==checked)` that say  `Syntax error, '(' expected` ,  `) expected` and  `) expected`  ! can someone help me ?

my code :

```
protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = Email.Text, Email = Email.Text };
    IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        if (chk1==checked)
        {
            signInManager.SignIn( user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
            IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
        } else 
            Response.Write("Sorry");

    }
    else 
    {
        ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `chk1` and `checked`??

Comment: @Sushil `chk1` is a  `<asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" runat="server" />`

Comment: your condition should be `if(chk1.checked == true)` or you can also use `if(chk1.checked)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checked` is a keyword in C#. I think what you want is to check if the `chk1` checkbox has a checked value, which you would do like this:

```
if(chk1.Checked == true)
{

}
```

or more simply:

```
if(chk1.Checked)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

"checked" is a reserved keyword in C#.  I think you are confusing the compiler by using it.  Try renaming that.

Answer (score 2):

`Checked` is the boolean property of `chk1`, therefore the correct way for your needs will be:

```
protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = Email.Text, Email = Email.Text };
    IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        if (chk1.Checked)
        {
            signInManager.SignIn( user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
            IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
        } else 
            Response.Write("Sorry");

    }
    else 
    {
        ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```